# as3 / flex builder - is it possible to change the color of a trace statement?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, flexbuilder, trace

i suspect the answer here is "no",
but i'm wondering if it's possible to set the color of trace statements which appear in flex's console pane.  ie, i have a few "levels" of log statements, and i'd like the warnings and errors to really stand out.

tia,
Orion

Answer (score 4):

99% sure you can't. Would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the trace panel is pretty limited. Most people either write their own log viewer, or use one of the many many 3rd party ones. Here's a few random ones:

- http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/
- http://code.google.com/p/osflash-xray/
- http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can color the trace by preceeding the trace with a "X:" where X is a number from 0-5

for example : 0+": XYZ";